# how can i update a field from the textinput on change react native

Tags: react-native, onchange, textinput

i have data from an api what i want to do is update the item.qty textInput below so that each time the number is changed it substracts the value from the qty_total textInput so lets say the value in qty is 5 and the qty_total is 15 if the user changes the qty from 5 to 10 the total will go down from 15 to 10 , here is my code so far

PS : i dont want to post it on the api yet i just want it on view at the momemet

```
  import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { View, Text, FlatList, TextInput, StyleSheet, Animated, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';
import AxiosInstance from '../../../helper/axiosHelper';

export default function MainList({ prodData, setProdData }) {
    const [ selectedRow, setSelectedRow ] = useState([]);
    const [ tempData, setTempData ] = useState([]);

    const springanim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    const listanimation = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

    useEffect(() => {
        AxiosInstance.get('/getProdOrders?r_date=2021-07-24&r_force_xtra=0').then((res) => {
            setTempData(res.data);
            console.log(tempData);
        });
    }, []);

    
    const ProdElem = ({ item, index }) => {
        let bgColor = index % 2 === 0 ? '#363434' : '#5a5656';

        return (
            <View style={[ { ...styles.container, backgroundColor: bgColor } ]}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleSelectedRow(item)}>
                    <Text style={styles.productName} numberOfLines={1}>
                        {item.product_name}
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={styles.subContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.qty_readOnly}>
                        <Text style={styles.qty_readOnlyText}>{item.qty_last}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.qty}
                        keyboardType='numeric'
                        name='qty'>
                        {item.qty}
                    </TextInput>
                    <TextInput style={styles.qty} keyboardType='numeric'>
                        {item.qty_total}
                    </TextInput>
                    <View style={styles.qty_readOnly}>
                        <Text style={styles.qty_readOnlyText}>{item.qty_post_order}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    };

    const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        let sumPre = 0,
            sumExtra = 0,
            sumTotal = 0,
            sumAvailabe = 0;

        item.data.forEach((e) => {
            sumPre += e.qty_last;
            sumExtra += e.qty;
            sumTotal += e.qty_total;
            sumAvailabe += e.qty_post_order;
        });

        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    listKey={(item, index) => 'D' + index.toString()}
                    data={item.data}
                    renderItem={ProdElem}
                    keyExtractor={(e) => e.product}
                />

                <View style={styles.categoryContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.categoryName}>{item.title}</Text>
                    <View style={styles.totals}>
                        <Text style={styles.total_qty_readonly}>{sumPre}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.total_qty}>{sumExtra}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.total_qty}>{sumTotal}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.total_qty_readonly}>{sumAvailabe}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    };
    useEffect(
        () => {
            Animate(false);
        },
        [ springanim ]
    );

    return (
        <View>
            <Animated.View style={{ paddingBottom: listanimation }}>
                <FlatList data={prodData} listKey={'cat'} keyExtractor={(item) => item.id} renderItem={renderItem} />
            </Animated.View>
            <Animated.View
                style={{
                    position        : 'absolute',
                    fontSize        : 25,
                    backgroundColor : 'white',
                    width           : Dimensions.get('screen').width,
                    padding         : 20,
                    bottom          : springanim
                }}>
                <Text>
                    Name: {selectedRow.product_name} <Text style={{ color: '#a0a0a0' }}>/ {selectedRow.revision}</Text>
                </Text>
                <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Kind: {selectedRow.kind}</Text>
                <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>PCS: {selectedRow.qty_total}</Text>
                <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Available: {selectedRow.qty}</Text>
            </Animated.View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of textinput is to get user input you used it for display data which in not required just add text where you need to just display data like in your case qty_total changes automatically while you make changes in qty so make it text

go through TextInput documentation for it.

just add extra state for quantity selecter suppose

this is logic for take input for quantity from user where user will provide required quantity
const [qty,setqty]=useState(0)

and in your textinput for quantity which is entered by user
ad

```
value={qty}
   onChangeText={(val)=>setqty(val)}
```

after that you can display total through text
like

```
<Text>{item.qty_total-qty}</Text>
```